# Can not make desired pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make a pandas dataframe using 2 paramters as columns. But it makes a dataframe transpose of what I need. 
I have `a` and `b` as column parameters as follows:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[11,22,33,44,55]

pd.DataFrame([a,b])
```

This gives the following dataframe:

```
    0   1   2   3   4 
0   1   2   3   4   5
1   11  22  33  44  55
```

However, I want the dataframe as:

```
    0   1 
0   1   11
1   2   22
2   3   33
3   4   44
4   5   55
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([a,b]).T
```

Or use `zip`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, b)))
#pandas 0.24+
#df = pd.DataFrame(zip(a, b))
```

---

```
print (df)
   0   1
0  1  11
1  2  22
2  3  33
3  4  44
4  5  55
```

Also is possible specify column names by dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})
print (df)
   a   b
0  1  11
1  2  22
2  3  33
3  4  44
4  5  55
```

Answer (score 2):

Dataframe has transpose function. The property T is an accessor to the method transpose()

```
pd.DataFrame([a,b]).T
```

or

```
pd.DataFrame([a,b]).transpose()
```

Comment: Solution is in my answer already.

Comment: I saw your answer after I posted mine.